# jQuery parse href for key value pairs

Tags: jquery, href

I want to be able to extract a couple of key value pairs (if they exist) from a href. Assume example hrefs like:

```
http://server/index.pl?foo=bar&baz=123
http://server/index.pl?foo=bar
```

Basically baz may not exist. Using jQuery I'm capturing this on click function, I'd like to be able to find out what the values are (if they exist).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I've used in the past for this is a simple function like this:

```
var $_GET = {};
document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
function decode(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(s).replace(/\+/g, " ");
}
$_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});
```

Then the `$_GET` variable contains everything.  `$_GET.baz` would return `123` for example.  You could also access them like `$_GET["baz"]` if you needed to type in strings with spaces.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [JQuery URL parser](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/urlParser) to achieve this. Here is an example where an object of the parameters is returned:

```
$.url('http://allmarkedup.com?sky=blue&grass=green').param(); // returns { 'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find many solutions on the net, take a look at [parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri), for example.